# tilt SurfaceView with its content

Tags: android, webrtc, android-canvas, surfaceview

I need to tilt my `SurfaceView` by certain angle. `SurfaceView` renders a frame from WebRTC. But the render is always vertical. I need to rotate it by certain angle, say 30 degrees. I tried setting up `setWillNotDraw(false);` and adding this to my `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.rotate(30, 220, 290);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

This does not seem to work at all.
Here is my SurfaceView class:

```
public class SurfaceViewRenderer extends SurfaceView implements Callback, Callbacks {
private static final String TAG = "SurfaceViewRenderer";
private final String resourceName = this.getResourceName();
private final VideoLayoutMeasure videoLayoutMeasure = new VideoLayoutMeasure();
private final EglRenderer eglRenderer;
private RendererEvents rendererEvents;
private final Object layoutLock = new Object();
private boolean isFirstFrameRendered;
private int rotatedFrameWidth;
private int rotatedFrameHeight;
private int frameRotation;
private boolean enableFixedSize;
private int surfaceWidth;
private int surfaceHeight;

public SurfaceViewRenderer(Context context) {
  super(context);
  this.eglRenderer = new EglRenderer(this.resourceName);
  this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

public SurfaceViewRenderer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  this.eglRenderer = new EglRenderer(this.resourceName);
  this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public void init(org.webrtc.EglBase.Context sharedContext, RendererEvents rendererEvents) {
  this.init(sharedContext, rendererEvents, EglBase.CONFIG_PLAIN, new GlRectDrawer());
}

public void init(org.webrtc.EglBase.Context sharedContext, RendererEvents rendererEvents, int[] configAttributes, GlDrawer drawer) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.rendererEvents = rendererEvents;
  Object var5 = this.layoutLock;
  synchronized(this.layoutLock) {
    this.rotatedFrameWidth = 0;
    this.rotatedFrameHeight = 0;
    this.frameRotation = 0;
  }

  this.eglRenderer.init(sharedContext, configAttributes, drawer);
}

public void release() {
  this.eglRenderer.release();
}

public void addFrameListener(FrameListener listener, float scale, GlDrawer drawer) {
  this.eglRenderer.addFrameListener(listener, scale, drawer);
}

public void addFrameListener(FrameListener listener, float scale) {
  this.eglRenderer.addFrameListener(listener, scale);
}

public void removeFrameListener(FrameListener listener) {
  this.eglRenderer.removeFrameListener(listener);
}

public void setEnableHardwareScaler(boolean enabled) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.enableFixedSize = enabled;
  this.updateSurfaceSize();
}

public void setMirror(boolean mirror) {
  this.eglRenderer.setMirror(mirror);
}

public void setScalingType(ScalingType scalingType) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.videoLayoutMeasure.setScalingType(scalingType);
}

public void setScalingType(ScalingType scalingTypeMatchOrientation, ScalingType scalingTypeMismatchOrientation) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.videoLayoutMeasure.setScalingType(scalingTypeMatchOrientation, scalingTypeMismatchOrientation);
}

public void setFpsReduction(float fps) {
  this.eglRenderer.setFpsReduction(fps);
}

public void disableFpsReduction() {
  this.eglRenderer.disableFpsReduction();
}

public void pauseVideo() {
  this.eglRenderer.pauseVideo();
}

public void renderFrame(I420Frame frame) {
  this.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents(frame);
  this.eglRenderer.renderFrame(frame);
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  Object var4 = this.layoutLock;
  Point size;
  synchronized(this.layoutLock) {
    size = this.videoLayoutMeasure.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec, this.rotatedFrameWidth, this.rotatedFrameHeight);
  }

  this.setMeasuredDimension(size.x, size.y);
  this.logD("onMeasure(). New size: " + size.x + "x" + size.y);
}

protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.eglRenderer.setLayoutAspectRatio((float)(right - left) / (float)(bottom - top));
  this.updateSurfaceSize();
}

private void updateSurfaceSize() {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  Object var1 = this.layoutLock;
  synchronized(this.layoutLock) {
    if(this.enableFixedSize && this.rotatedFrameWidth != 0 && this.rotatedFrameHeight != 0 && this.getWidth() != 0 && this.getHeight() != 0) {
      float layoutAspectRatio = (float)this.getWidth() / (float)this.getHeight();
      float frameAspectRatio = (float)this.rotatedFrameWidth / (float)this.rotatedFrameHeight;
      int drawnFrameWidth;
      int drawnFrameHeight;
      if(frameAspectRatio > layoutAspectRatio) {
        drawnFrameWidth = (int)((float)this.rotatedFrameHeight * layoutAspectRatio);
        drawnFrameHeight = this.rotatedFrameHeight;
      } else {
        drawnFrameWidth = this.rotatedFrameWidth;
        drawnFrameHeight = (int)((float)this.rotatedFrameWidth / layoutAspectRatio);
      }

      int width = Math.min(this.getWidth(), drawnFrameWidth);
      int height = Math.min(this.getHeight(), drawnFrameHeight);
      this.logD("updateSurfaceSize. Layout size: " + this.getWidth() + "x" + this.getHeight() + ", frame size: " + this.rotatedFrameWidth + "x" + this.rotatedFrameHeight + ", requested surface size: " + width + "x" + height + ", old surface size: " + this.surfaceWidth + "x" + this.surfaceHeight);
      if(width != this.surfaceWidth || height != this.surfaceHeight) {
        this.surfaceWidth = width;
        this.surfaceHeight = height;
        this.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
      }
    } else {
      this.surfaceWidth = this.surfaceHeight = 0;
      this.getHolder().setSizeFromLayout();
    }

  }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.eglRenderer.createEglSurface(holder.getSurface());
  this.surfaceWidth = this.surfaceHeight = 0;
  this.updateSurfaceSize();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  final CountDownLatch completionLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  this.eglRenderer.releaseEglSurface(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      completionLatch.countDown();
    }
  });
  ThreadUtils.awaitUninterruptibly(completionLatch);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
  ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
  this.logD("surfaceChanged: format: " + format + " size: " + width + "x" + height);
}

private String getResourceName() {
  try {
    return this.getResources().getResourceEntryName(this.getId()) + ": ";
  } catch (NotFoundException var2) {
    return "";
  }
}

private void updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents(I420Frame frame) {
  Object var2 = this.layoutLock;
  synchronized(this.layoutLock) {
    if(!this.isFirstFrameRendered) {
      this.isFirstFrameRendered = true;
      this.logD("Reporting first rendered frame.");
      if(this.rendererEvents != null) {
        this.rendererEvents.onFirstFrameRendered();
      }
    }

    if(this.rotatedFrameWidth != frame.rotatedWidth() || this.rotatedFrameHeight != frame.rotatedHeight() || this.frameRotation != frame.rotationDegree) {
      this.logD("Reporting frame resolution changed to " + frame.width + "x" + frame.height + " with rotation " + frame.rotationDegree);
      if(this.rendererEvents != null) {
        this.rendererEvents.onFrameResolutionChanged(frame.width, frame.height, frame.rotationDegree);
      }

      this.rotatedFrameWidth = frame.rotatedWidth();
      this.rotatedFrameHeight = frame.rotatedHeight();
      this.frameRotation = frame.rotationDegree;
      this.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          SurfaceViewRenderer.this.updateSurfaceSize();
          SurfaceViewRenderer.this.requestLayout();
        }
      });
    }

  }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.rotate(180, 220, 290);
  super.onDraw(canvas);
}

private void logD(String string) {
  Logging.d("SurfaceViewRenderer", this.resourceName + string);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) instead.

From the documentation:

> Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be moved, transformed, animated, etc.